# When using xsd.exe, which File option should I choose and why?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd.exe

I have received a xsd file from a third party vendor for some XML files we currently receive. In order to process the files, I have used `xsd.exe` to generate my classes. I see that there are two command line options available, namely:

- `/c[lasses]` and
- `/d[ataset]`

My question is noobish at best, which option should I choose and why?

PS:
*I have tried both, however, at present, the `/d` option results in some error regarding nested tables. The `/c` option does work for me although it requires a lot of data-mapping to my domain objects.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/c`. A `DataSet` is an in-memory representation of a relational database. Not all XML Schema files map to a relational database model. The error message you received was no doubt because your schemas cannot map to the relational model.

`/c` will produce classes that can be loaded from or saved to an XML file by using the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: In my case, since the xml files are in no way close to any relational model, would `/c` would be the better option? For future reference though, and for clarity, am I correct in saying that if xml data is 'relational' in nature, use `/d` else use `/c`

Comment: In your case, `/c` is the only option. When I say "relational", I mean in the formal sense. For instance, strict parent/child/grandchild. Can't have the same "grandchild" as the child of two different parents.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise choosing the 'c' option as datasets are evil. Pure evil.

Answer (score 0):

I think /d will give you a dataset to work with the data of the XML.
The /c will generate the classes you need to work with the data.

Now, that's your choice, you'll need data-mapping to your domain objects for both options, imho.

Comment: What 'date' are you referring to? Yes, I am aware what each option will provide me my question relates to which option to choose.

Comment: Sorry, I meant... data. Which option is up to you. I prefer to use the option to create the classes, since I've more control over that.